# UIpickerView populating multiple uitextFields in the same ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uipickerview

Hi I am developing an iphone app where I have populated a uipickerview and it works great with one uitextfield. But I have 6 uitextfield I need to populate and I am using the same uipickerview for each UItextfield.

I have working the Ipickerview loaded with array objects and it pops up when each field is touched. The problem is with the code below the UItextfields share the same data from the picker.

I can not figure out how to code so each field gets it own data from the UIPickerView row.
What Am I doing wrong? Any coding suggestions?

Thanks

@implementation BestViewController

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *)thePickerView 
{ return 1; }

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:                    (NSInteger)component 
{return [list count]; }

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{return [list objectAtIndex:row]; }

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:      (NSInteger)component 
{ 
    uitextfield1.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];   
    utitextfield2.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

    uitextfield1.inputView = pickerView; 
uitextfield2.inputView = pickerView;

list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
[list addObject:@"a"];
[list addObject:@"b"];
    [list addObject:@"c"];  
    [list addObject:@"d"];
}
```

Comment: What is happening? Is the text of your text fields changed?

Comment: In your code example, one selection of a picker row would update two UITextFields at the same time. This is intended, right?

Comment: No, i want to select each UItextfield and enter the picker data independent of each other. the code I have works for one textfield. But the  way i have it coded above (which I know is wrong) it updates two field with the same data. I want each UITextfield to have data independent of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get hold of the current first responder and set its `text` property rather than explicitly setting a particular text field.

So,

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:      (NSInteger)component 
{ 
    // textFields is an NSArray holding each of the textfields that are using the picker as an input view
    for (UITextField textField in textFields)
    {
        if ([textField isFirstResponder])
        {
            textField.text = [list objectAtIndex:row];
            break;
        }
    }    
}
```

There may be a more elegant way to find the current first responder, this is off the top of my head. `textFields` could possibly be an IBOutletCollection, but I haven't used those myself so I can't speak with much authority.

Comment: Thanks so I added this to my M file, what changes do i need to make to my   (void)pickerView code  ?                                 -(BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

Comment: No, the picker isn't the first responder, your textfield is. The active text field will return YES to isFirstResponder.

Comment: sorry let me retype my response. in my M file I added -(BOOL) acceptsFirstResponder { return YES; }  my question is how do I point my -(void)pickerView to that active UITextfield? Now I name a specific field  uitextfield1.text = [list objectAtIndex:row] I want it to be generic and load the active field.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it:

First, define several different pickers. Of course you use the same `UIPickerView` but you change one property that helps you distinguish them. There is different data for (almost) each text field. One convenient property that Apple designed exactly for this purpose is the `tag`, an arbitrary integer available to every `UIView`. You can assign the same tags to the `UITextField`s.

For example:

```
#define kFirstTextField 101
#define kSecondTextField 102
#define kThirdTextField 103
//... etc
```

In the method when the text field is touched:

```
[myPickerView setHidden:NO];  // or however you show the picker
[myPickerView setTag:textField.tag];
[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
```

In the data methods of the picker:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview 
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row  
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    if (thePickerView.tag==kFirstTextField) 
        { return [list1 count]; }
    if (thePickerView.tag==kSecondTextField) 
        { return [anotherOrTheSameList count]; }
// of course, you can also use a switch statement
    return [defaultList count];
}
```

Do something similar in the `titleForRow:` method.
Finally, when something is picked, discriminate again by tag:

```
-(void)   pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerview 
        didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row 
         inComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{ 
    UITextField *field = (UITextField *) [thePickerview.superview viewWithTag:thePickerview.tag];   
// this assumes the UIPickerView is the subview of the same view as the UITextFields
    if (thePickerview.tag==kFirstTextField) 
        { field.text = [list1 objectAtIndex:row]; }
    if (thePickerview.tag==kSecondTextField)
        { field.text = [anotherOrTheSameList objectAtIndex:row]; }
    // etc.
    // alternatively:
    field.text = [self pickerView:thePickerview titleForRow:row forComponent:0];
}
```

Comment: My Goodness...where the hell you get these ideas...its brilliant. Thanks @Mundi :)